# HTML,CSS issue in IE

Tags: html, css

While I am creating a website I have given margin:0 auto for main div. It aligned properly but while I am zooming out the window in IE it is going to left alignment.

```
  <style>
    body         { margin:0; padding:0 }
    #container   { margin:0; padding:0 }
    #container p { margin:0; padding:0 }
  </style>
  <html>
    <body>
      <div id="container"> <p>Chriz</p> </div> 
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Which version of IE, and which version of Windows? These things matter...

Comment: You should post some example code.

Comment: <style>
body{margin:0;padding:0}
#container{margin:0;padding:0}
#container p{margin:0;padding:0}
</style>

<html>
<body>

<div id="container">
 <p>Chriz</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a fixed width on it? it should read

```
#mainDiv{
    margin:0 auto;
    width: 900px;
}
```

Comment: This will center align a block element. However you have to consider this bad practice as you are creating a fixed width element. Killer for a responsive, flexible design

Answer (score 0):

hi now used  to this css

```
body{
text-align:center;
}

#container{
margin:0 auto;
text-align:left;
}
```